# CSS: 100% width and background?

Tags: css, background, width

In my page have 2-3 sections that have 100% width and background. When I open it on full screen everything is ok but when the screen is smaller than 960px (width of content in this sections) background image is not the entire page. The right side whis is hidden in firtst moment haven't background - it's white. You can see what I mean here: http://micobg.net/10th/

Comment: read this : http://www.whatstyle.net/articles/48/css_tricks_1_100_percent_width_in_a_variable_width_container

Comment: You can find useful information in [stackoverflow.com/questions/2083831/css-background-image-does-not-fill-when-scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083831/css-background-image-does-not-fill-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 24):

Simply add the `background-size:100%` style to the element where you applied `background-image`. Works in Firefox, Safari, and Opera. For example:

```
<style>
.divWithBgImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: url(image.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%; //propotional resize
/*
  background-size: 100% 100%; //stretch resize
*/
}
</style>
<div class="divWithBgImage">
  some contents
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Regarding to [this](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) article, you should to use `cover` as well:

```
html { 
  background: url(PATH_TO_IMAGE) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use background min-width:960px; instead of width:100%;
Cheers