# Issue styling GWT root panel with CSS

Tags: css, gwt

I have the following CSS class declared for my base root panel.

```
#rootPanel
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-image:url("../images/green013.jpg");
}
```

My widgets are all positioned using %ages so they appear in the centre of the viewpanel regardless of the width of the Screen.  Problem is with my background image.  It doesn't repeat to fill the background which it does fine if I set my root panel dimensions to be say 800px and 800px.  Seems it doesn't repeat if I use %ages for some reason? Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Where you mentioned background-repeat:none; ??

Comment: It repeats by default does it not?  I didn't specify Repeat when I set the width to be 800px and it repeats with no problem

Comment: yup.By default it will repeat if you not mentioned x or y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get  rid off the % `height` and `width` and set them in `Pixel` regardless of the `browser size` ,then use

```
RootPanel.get().setHeight(Window.getClientHeight()+"px"); 

RootPanel.get().setWidth(Window.getClientWidth()+"px");
```

Then apply your style.

Comment: A1  :) Exactly what I want but ..... The background image still won't repeat but I can live with that.

Comment: You set the Height instead the Width is the second line.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right. image is not repeat in %. for repeat image, you have to specify height & width in Pixel. I am facing same problem when I set into pixel, it will work!!.

Comment: Hmmm, setting pixel width is not an option as I want my UI to look similar regardless of the width of the UI

Comment: you can do it by using `Window.getClientWidth() + "px" `. is there any issue with it!! or you can do such as refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083831/css-background-image-does-not-fill-when-scrolling