# Bootstrap: White space when scrolling horizontally after disabling responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having some trouble with horizontal scrolling after disabling responsiveness per the bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive) (running v3.0.2).

When minimizing the window below the width set on the container, the background becomes white when scrolling horizontally.

I tried this:

```
html {
  width: auto !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

...but this doesn't allow for any horizontal scrolling. Looking to be able to scroll horizontally with the background rendered correctly. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: @LloydBanks I'm having a bit of trouble recreating the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/U4ecA/1/ Basically, when I scroll to the right the background is completely blank/white. Obviously, this doesn't happen in the jsfiddle I created, the background remains red upon scrolling horizontally.

Comment: Do you have a dev link for your page you can post?

Comment: @LloydBanks I find a similar problem here with a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083831/css-background-image-does-not-fill-when-scrolling. However, now i'm having trouble because the right side of my navbar seems to disappear when I minimize the window past a certain point.

Comment: Actually, seems like that was a problem even before setting a min-width...so it's probably unrelated

Comment: okay, that's been solved, too. forgot to remove one of the navbar-collapse attributes. I appreciate your time @LloydBanks , eventually led me to an answer