# how to overlay a new div over entire body of HTML using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having similar issue as posted [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083831/css-background-image-does-not-fill-when-scrolling). During Ajax request, I am trying to put background image of loading icon and greyed background, somehow the greyed background does not extend to the bottom of the page. As I scroll, it goes away.
I tried remedies suggested in that post, but none helped.
I thought of re-insering a brand new div that covers entire body of html and have background-greyed with loading icon. But I really don't know how to do that.
So the question is using Jquery

1. I have my HTML with body that contain various elements.
2. Make the current contents invisible or greyed out, put a new div that covers entire the body of HTML (basically on top of the current HTML body) and fill it with greyed-background

Any help?

Comment: Tried fixed positioning?

Comment: proTip: whenever using ajax, and you don't want scrolling, on `beforeSend`, set `$('html, body').css('overflow', 'hidden !important')` to disallow scrolling. then in the `complete` or 'success' callback, simply reverse it, `$('html, body').css('overflow', '')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you will need a `div` that is hidden most of the time, preferable with `display: none`, and then you will call a `$( ".coverAll" ).show();` when you want to cover the screen. The styles for the div are below. By z-index'ing the div ABOVE the rest of your content, you effectively hide that content behind it.

HTML:

```
<div class="coverAll">Loading...</div>
```

Css:

```
.coverAll {
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #CCC;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I prefer using the hidden attr. `<div class="coverAll" hidden>Loading...</div>`, then `element.hidden ^= 1` to toggle.

Comment: @bjb568 that's great! ... if you know your target audience is all using HTML5 compatible browsers ...

Comment: `[hidden] { display: none }`?

Comment: thanks, I tried the one from below thinking jquery API will do it nicer than me hard-coding, but I have other problems there. so will test this now.

Answer (score 1):

I use jQuery BlockUI Plugin for disabling user interaction with the page during ajax requests here's a link:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Include the `jquery.blockUI.js` file, then add the following line to a script tag on the page:

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
```

User interaction will be blocked during all jQuery ajax requests on the page.

The link above includes several ways to customize.  The example above uses all the defaults.